# Container View Controller how to find and provide size of child view controller in sizeForChildContentContainer

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicontainerview

When a change in size happens for a View Controller (**VC**) (e.g. on device rotation), we all know this method is called:

> -(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
>         withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator

The `size` parameter is the size of that view controller's view **after** the size change.

---

For a view controller (**ChildVC**) that is the child of a custom container view controller (**ContainerVC**), then by default the `size` parameter given by that method is the *ContainerVC*'s size.

This all works until the *ChildVC*'s view is smaller than the *ContainerVC*'s view. In that case, the *ContainerVC* needs to implement this method:

> -(CGSize)sizeForChildContentContainer:(id)container withParentContainerSize:(CGSize)parentSize

---

**Question:** How can I possibly deduct the size of the *ChildVC*'s view inside that method?

The method is called too early, before the size/trait collection has even changed -> calling `[self.vc layoutIfNeeded];` to update the constraints does not work (constraints haven't yet been updated to respond to trait change).

The only clue I have at that point is the method's `parentSize` parameter which is indeed the future size.

---

Visual example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

- In Green: ContainerVC
- In Purple: ChildVC
- In Blue: Constraints between

[image: iPhone Portrait]
[image: iPhone Landscape]

---

Edit: I am still very much interested in having an answer to this question! But I'm starting to think maybe this problem cannot be dealt with AutoLayout, and needs to be done by hand.

---

Edit2: Here is the flow of events as described by Apple. I think it shows that we need to know in advance what the size of the ChildViewController will be. This may show that this logic may need to be done by hand...

[image: Updating a view controller’s traits and view size]

Answer (score 0):

I now believe this cannot be achieved using Auto-Layout. I opened a support ticket with Apple but they were not able to provide me with a satisfactory answer unfortunately.